# change specific field value in serializer class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like this

```
class ProjectTemplate(models.Model):
    project_template_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    org_id = models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'project_template'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and a serializer class like this

```
class ProjectTemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
         model = ProjectTemplate
```

in the created_by field i am storing the user id in the db, when listing the project templates, basically i'll get user id's for create_by field,

how to change my serializer class to get a dict like this

```
{"user_id":id,"user_name":name}
```

for created_by field

Comment: Why not just make a foreign key to a user?..

Comment: ok, even it is foreign key to the user it will store primary_key field value of user only, right?, then how to do that?

Comment: No... it provides you a way of referencing a user instance.. foreign keys are covered in detail in the documentation. Not far from the part where it says an `id` primary key field is automatically provided for you

Comment: yeah, i'm actually asking about how to change specific field value in serializer class

Comment: Your problem is a byproduct of the fact that you're model is set up incorrectly in the first place, fixing the model makes this problem simple to fix. Otherwise, any solution is just a hack

Comment: ok, just assume it is referencing to user model, then what is the solution to change value of created_by field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Sayse said, you'd better make a foreign key to a user like this:

```
create_by = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="project_user")
```

Then you can access the info from user like user_name or something by:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id", "user_name")

class ProjectTemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    user = UserSerializer(source="user", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
         model = ProjectTemplate
         fields = (
            "id", "user",
         )
```